# EditorJS Image upload with Angular to Firestorage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, editorjs

I'm using editor JS for an Angular app. When I use the Image tool with Firebase I get "cannot read property 'ref' of undefined". Here's my .ts file:

```
image: {
      class: ImageTool,
      config: {
        uploader:{
          
          uploadByFile(file : File) {
            const path = `post/${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;
            const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
            const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              task.snapshotChanges()
                .pipe(
                  finalize( () => {
                    ref.getDownloadURL()
                      .subscribe(url => {
                        console.log(url);
                        let res = {
                          success: 1,
                          file: {
                            url : url
                          }
                        }
                        resolve(res);
                      },error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(error);
                      })
                  }))
                .subscribe( url => {
                  if(url){
                    console.log(url);
                  }
                })
            })
          }
      }
  }
}
```

How should firebase storage be defined in Image block? If I do only this.storage.upload I get the same error

Comment: Could you debug `this.storage` - the error is stating that it is undefined. normally this is imported from the state storage so it might be a scope/context issue. if you aren't using local states - you will have to import Firebase as is and reference the storage object from the Firebase App instance.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a scope issue. Not sure if this is the appropriate solution but defining const self = this; made it work